# creating a text file and saving data in android

Tags: android, file

I am new to programming android apps.

In the following code, I want to take input from user through a number of EditTexts and then save them into a file. I use android studio and after giving the inputs, I checked the file and it is always empty. I try to display the contents and still get no output. What is wrong with the code?

Please help me.

```
public class user extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

    nextClick();
}

public void nextClick()
{
    final Context context = this;
    Button next =(Button) findViewById(R.id.userNext);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           try {
               EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
               EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.designation);
               EditText e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.orgname);
               EditText e4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
               EditText e5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.city);
               EditText e6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.state);
               EditText e7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zip);
               FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("data.txt", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
               OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);

               osw.write(e1.toString());

               fos.flush();
               fos.close();
           }
           catch(Exception e) {
           }
            try
                  {
              FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("data.txt");

               while(fis.read()!=-1)
               {
                   System.out.println((char)fis.read());
               }

           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {

           }
           Intent intent3 = new Intent(context,com.example.cheruvu.rs.user2.class);
           startActivity(intent3);
       }
   });
}

}
```

Comment: for simplicity, i was trying to take input from only one of the edittexts

Comment: have you declared write external storage permission in your manifest

Comment: but, i want to store it in internal memory ?

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: `catch(Exception e) {
           }` don't do that.

Comment: @BidhanA: that does not make any sense. That's not how imports work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **getText()** from the **EditText** fields when you are writing to the file , as shown below

`osw.write(e1.getText().toString());`

Comment: oops! i am sorry. I included that now and got the following:                                               
 Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.cheruvu.rs/com.example.cheruvu.rs.user}
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.example.cheruvu.rs/com.example.cheruvu.rs.user}
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477)
            at.................
how to handle these exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

What about this. This will create file on your phone (not SDcard)

```
File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "MyFileName");
FileOutpuStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
```

Comment: not working :( I actually created the file in the res directory and then added the code. now, I tried as you told and it is still not working.

Comment: Instead of getAbsolutePath() try getAbsoluteFile()

Comment: can u tell me where the file is created because i cant find it in the res directory? anyways, still not getting the output :(

Comment: It is created in a root folder of your phone. My Files -> All Files -> Device storage

Comment: ok, so the file cannot be accessed ? but I want full access to the file so that I can export the data from the file later. Can i do this?

Comment: Please provide more information ? You can't open/write/read ?

Comment: i have a file  named data.txt in the res directory. I am trying to write data into it and then read the file. Unfortunately, no data is being copied into the file and therefore nothing is being read and displayed.

Comment: Because path to File is wrong. Example, that I gave you before, writes into root folder. In order to write into "res" directory. You should have something like File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + File.separator + "res"+ File.separator +  "data.txt");

Comment: Check if the path is correct(adjust if needed) and all permissions

Comment: the data.txt is directly under the res directory and hence the above path mentioned by you is correct , i have included the write external storage and read external storage permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml . it is still not working. where have i gone wrong?

Comment: Try PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(myFile); pw.println("Your text");

Comment: nope,not working !! I think i am not specifying the path of the file correctly, from where do I need to specify? because res is in main and main is in src?

Comment: Hey, now i am getting the output , i.e , whatever I enter in the edit text is being displayed. but using File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + File.separator +"data.txt"); , the file is created everytime the code is run , right? what if i want to create the file once and then keep appending data into it?

Comment: Check if file exist. If yes append to the end of it

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code with this and see if it works

```
public class user extends Activity {

EditText e1;
EditText e2;
EditText e3;
EditText e4;
EditText e5;
EditText e6; 
EditText e7; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

    e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.designation);
    e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.orgname);
    e4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    e5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.city);
    e6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.state);
    e7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.zip);

    nextClick();
}

public void nextClick()
{
    final Context context = this;
    Button next =(Button) findViewById(R.id.userNext);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           try {

               FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("data.txt", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
               OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);

               osw.write(e1.getText().toString());

               fos.flush();
               fos.close();
           }
           catch(Exception e) {
           }
            try
                  {
              FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("data.txt");

               while(fis.read()!=-1)
               {
                   System.out.println((char)fis.read());
               }

           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {

           }
           Intent intent3 = new Intent(context,com.example.cheruvu.rs.user2.class);
           startActivity(intent3);
       }
   });
}

}
```

Comment: not working ....I am going nuts, not able to understand whats wrong with this code because nothing works in my code :(

Comment: Did you try using a different mode? Like `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` ?